# R - list files recursively in specific subdirectories

Tags: r, list, file, subdirectory

I am trying to list files that are organized as following:

```
/Volumes/Macintosh HD 2/data/cmip5/historical/

----clt
-----------------------file1.txt
-----------------------file2.txt
---------------models
-----------------------file1.txt
-----------------------file2.txt

----hurs
-----------------------file1.txt
-----------------------file2.txt
---------------models
-----------------------file1.txt
-----------------------file2.txt

----precip
-----------------------file1.txt
-----------------------file2.txt
---------------models
-----------------------file1.txt
-----------------------file2.txt

----temp
-----------------------file1.txt 
-----------------------file2.txt 
---------------models
-----------------------file1.txt 
-----------------------file2.txt 

----wind
-----------------------file1.txt 
-----------------------file2.txt 
---------------models
-----------------------file1.txt 
-----------------------file2.txt
```

What I would like to do is list, in one single list, all files contained in the subdirectories "models".

What I tried, and did **not** work, was this command:

```
> Sys.glob(file.path('/Volumes/Macintosh HD 2/data/cmip5/historical/', "models","*.txt"))
character(0)
```

Is there any straighforward way to achieve this with R?

Comment: `list.files('./path/to/historical', recursive = TRUE)`

Comment: @rawr it doesn't work because I need to list only the files in the subdirectories `models`

Answer (score 5):

Turns out that it was way easier than I thought:

```
Sys.glob('/Volumes/Macintosh HD 2/data/cmip5/historical/*/models/*.txt')
```

It seems like it is impossible to find something R can **not** do.